# Insert data into MySql using nusoap web service?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, soap, nusoap

I have created this code to insert data into my database using nusoap. Everything is working fine but the data are not inserted at my database.

Here is the code

```
require_once('nusoap/nusoap.php');

$server = new soap_server();

$server->configureWSDL('Insert Order', 'urn:InsertOrder');

$server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';

$server->register(
    'InsertOrder',
    array('FirstName' => 'xsd:Testing', 'LastName' => 'xsd:NuSoap'),
    array('return' =>'xsd:boolean'),
    'urn:InsertOrderwsdl', 
    'urn:InsertOrderwsdl#InsertOrder', 
    'rpc', 
    'literal'      
);

function InsertOrder($FirstName, $LastName) {

$connect = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","");
if ($connect) {       
    if(mysql_select_db("database", $connect)) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO myuser SET FirstName='$FirstName',     LastName='$LastName'");   
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Here is the wsdl file:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:InsertOrder">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:InsertOrder">
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
</xsd:schema></types>
<message name="InsertOrderRequest">
<part name="FirstName" type="xsd:Testing"/>
<part name="LastName" type="xsd:NuSoap"/>
</message>
<message name="InsertOrderResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</message><portType name="Insert OrderPortType">
<operation name="InsertOrder">
<input message="tns:InsertOrderRequest"/>
<output message="tns:InsertOrderResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Insert OrderBinding" type="tns:Insert OrderPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="InsertOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:InsertOrderwsdl#InsertOrder" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:InsertOrderwsdl"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:InsertOrderwsdl"/>
</output>
</operation></binding>
<service name="Insert Order">
<port name="Insert OrderPort" binding="tns:Insert OrderBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost/nuSoap/MyService.php"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

At wsdl file the parameters and the output is ok. What i don't understand why is not putting these data into my database? i must miss something here. Anyone has any idea why is this happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code at all to narrow down where the problem lies?  For example, are the proper parameters being passed to your insert function? Have you considered adding error handling around your DB connection and query?

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i move the function InsertOrder it inserts the data into database but empty because it doesn't have the notion of FirstName and LastName variable. I think there is something wrong with that function. So the DB connection work fine. Thank you

Comment: why isnt the datatype of username and password string? `array('FirstName' => 'xsd:string', 'LastName' => 'xsd:string'),`. May I also suggest using `PDO's prepare` or `mysql_real_escape_string()` as mysql_* is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert statement seems more like an update statement. Could you change

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myuser SET FirstName='$FirstName',     LastName='$LastName'");
```

to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myuser(FirstName,LastName) values('$FirstName', '$LastName')");
```

Answer (score 0):

### my script has no error and it is inserting data into my mysql table via soap, and i hope you have done something wrong in your database connection. check again! or i think you have sql syntax error in your insert query. below is my code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO employee (ename) VALUES('".$employee_name."')";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if($res==true){
    return "Employee inserted";
}else{
    return "data not inserted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
array('FirstName' => 'xsd:Testing', 'LastName' => 'xsd:NuSoap'),

try this 
array('FirstName' => 'xsd:string', 'LastName' => 'xsd:string'),